# Symfony / SwiftMailer / Can't send email without spool

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I have a problem with email sending. I can't send email without spool.
In documentation I see just `$mailer->send();` http://symfony.com/doc/current/email.html

But for me, it does nothing. 
To send email, I have to do this:

```
            $mailer->send($message);
            $spool = $mailer->getTransport()->getSpool();
            $transport = $this->get('swiftmailer.transport.real');
            $spool->flushQueue($transport);
```

ContactType.php

```
    $builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class, [
            'required' => false
        ])
        ->add('email', EmailType::class)
        ->add('message', TextareaType::class);
```

Where can be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could define an non-spooled mailer and use that instead of the default one:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html#using-multiple-mailers